# Paypal Website Payments Pro - Get AVS/CVV

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am using Paypal Website Payments Pro currently.

**My question** is, how can I retrieve the `AVS/CVV` response code through the API, **after** a transaction has taken place. So I'm thinking all I need to do is send a `GET` request to some endpoint, with the transaction ID, and I am hoping the `AVS/CVV` will be included in the response.

There seems to be limited information on what is actually returned though.

**TLDR:** That said, is it possible to retrieve the AVS/CVV response code through the API, for Paypal Website Payments Pro, while providing a transaction ID (or similar) as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical `DoDirectPayment` Response

NVP Response:

```
TIMESTAMP=2015-04-01T07:09:23Z
CORRELATIONID=5d206d78a7eb2
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=15840636
AMT=0.01
CURRENCYCODE=USD
AVSCODE=X
CVV2MATCH=M
TRANSACTIONID=4XJ98999B8918783X
```

There is `GetTransactionDetails` API with transaction id as input parameter , which responds the following but won't get AVS,CVV in response.

NVP Response:

```
RECEIVERBUSINESS=us-30@cri.com
RECEIVEREMAIL=us-30@cri.com
RECEIVERID=XTV2XWLQDBBUL
PAYERID=RPP8F58J274JG
PAYERSTATUS=unverified
COUNTRYCODE=US
ADDRESSOWNER=PayPal
ADDRESSSTATUS=None
SALESTAX=0.00
SHIPAMOUNT=0.00
SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT=0.00
TIMESTAMP=2015-04-01T07:09:35Z
CORRELATIONID=6d04b6839b8a
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=15840636
FIRSTNAME=John
LASTNAME=Test
TRANSACTIONID=4XJ98999B8918783X
RECEIPTID=2178-2433-5782-0156
TRANSACTIONTYPE=webaccept
PAYMENTTYPE=instant
ORDERTIME=2015-04-01T07:09:22Z
AMT=0.01
FEEAMT=0.01
TAXAMT=0.00
CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed
PENDINGREASON=None
REASONCODE=None
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY=Ineligible
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE=None
L_QTY0=1
L_TAXAMT0=0.00
L_CURRENCYCODE0=USD
L_TAXABLE0=false
```

Comment: So then to confirm, avs/cvv is only available at the time of the transaction's creation? And so not available post transaction ? Thanks!